# Unexpected regular expression behaviour

Tags: ruby, regex

When running the following piece of code in ruby:

```
string = "\begin{theorem}[blaat] \label{thm:foo}"
pattern = /^\\begin\{(theorem|definition)\}(\[.+\])?\s\\label\{(thm|def):.+\}$/
if string =~ pattern then
    puts "match"    
else
    puts "no match"
end
```

I get a "no match" output.

However, when using the same pattern and string on [rubular](http://rubular.com/) I get a match.
The irregularities already start when using the above code with pattern:

```
/^\\begin/
```

and string `\begin`. This does not match using the above snippet, but it does on rubular.com

I'm using Ruby 1.9.1

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your input string. You have a backspace character `"\b"`. Try using a single-quoted string instead:

```
string = '\begin{theorem}[blaat] \label{thm:foo}'
```